PayPal Express transactions for digital products are not completed automatically since Magento 2.4.6 CLI
We have a Magento store for digital products. After purchase, the Standard PayPal Express Checkout amount is automatically collected and the invoice is sent via AutoInvoice. This worked perfectly for years up to Magento version 2.4.5-p7.
Without further changes other than updates from third-party providers, PayPal does not work correctly from version 2.4.6 with PHP 8.1.2. After the purchase, a gateway error appears in the order log with Exception message: PayPal-Gateway hat die Anfrage abgelehnt. A successful transaction has already been completed for this token (#10415: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details). The download article will be activated. However, the PayPal amount must be collected manually on the PayPal website as the transaction status is Pending. Magento therefore does not send an automatic invoice. The same process works perfectly for AmazonPay. Does anyone have a similar problem and a solution? Thank you very much!
